# Rcc Controller issue in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to use RCC controller in Unity3D : I simply import RCC packages that I took from a demo scene : rcc city.
In game-view rcc city it is working perfectly and looking good for view, but in scene-view it shows only color on every object.

[image]

I tried to solve this problem through youtube but I did not get any useful content please experts help me get rid of this.

Comment: that looks like a navmesh...   i bet its not visible at runtime

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read the documentation first on how to work with RCC before diving into using such an advanced controller.
The basic steps I could provide you are:

> 1. Create a new scene or open an existing one where you want to add the RCC controller.
> 2. Make sure you have a terrain or a ground plane where the car can be placed and driven.
> 3. Drag and drop the car model into your scene. Add the "RCC Car" component to your car model by clicking on "Add Component" in the Inspector window and searching for "RCC Car."
> 4. Adjust parameters such as engine power, torque, braking, suspension settings, and tire grip to match your desired car behavior.
> 5. Map your input controls (keyboard, joystick, or mobile) to the RCC controller's input functions. For example, connect the accelerator and brake inputs to the appropriate input axes.
> 6. Enter Play mode to test your car's behavior and controls.